# Why is capture option not working in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html-select, addeventlistener, event-bubbling, event-capturing

My `capture` option doesn't seem to be working in the `addEventListener`, it gives me the same console results whether I set it to `true` or `false`.

I checked the following:

1. Add `once: true` to the option object - this works, but capture doesn't
2. Replace `capture` with `useCapture` - this also doesn't seem to work and in both cases no error/warning messages
3. I read online that some (older e.g. chrome version less than 55) browsers don't support newer options such as `once` - I am using chrome v88 and tried opening the file with Safari too just in case it is a browser-related issue

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  console.log(this.classList.value);
}
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {capture: true}));
```

```css
.one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's either `div.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {capture: true})` or `div.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true)`. There's no `useCapture` option property. So yes, your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine for me:

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  console.log(this.classList.value);
}
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {
  capture: div.classList.contains('capture')
}));
```

```html
<div class="one capture">
  One
  <div class="two capture">
    Two
    <div class="three capture">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="one bubble">
  One
  <div class="two bubble">
    Two
    <div class="three bubble">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I realised that misunderstood what the final result for the capture option should be. It was working all this time :)

Answer (score 1):

He worked for me, maybe you see the same results, that's right, but the capture change the order of it.

If you use `capture: true` the output is:

> `one`
>   `two`
>   `three`

if `capture: false`, the output is:

> `three`
>   `two`
>   `one`

```js
function handleClick(e) { console.log(this.classList.value);}

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {capture: false}));
```

```css
main div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div class="three">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I realised that misunderstood what the final result for the capture option should be. It was working all this time :)